# Submitting Video files in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need help in submitting a video file using **AngularJS** (in an **Ionic** App) to a **PHP** server. The code works for images but not videos. A quick hint, I think the name of the file is been sent to the server but when I tried getting the size it shows `0`, which means the actual file wasn't sent.

**Index.php**

```
       <div class="list">
           <label>Video clip (for peculiar cases)</label>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">

             <input type="file" ng-model="image34" name="image34" id="image34" placeholder="" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile34(this)" valid-file >
            </label>
```

on select the uploadedFile34 function is triggered. see the code below

```
$scope.uploadedFile34=function(element)
    {
      $scope.currentFile34= element.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event){

     $scope.image_source = event.target.result

     $scope.$apply(function($scope){
      $scope.files34 = element.files;
    });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
```

on submitting the form I get the file this way

```
   $scope.image34=$scope.files34[0];
formData.append("image34", $scope.image34);
```

Using form data which works perfectly for images but not for videos. Please I really need help on this, all efforts to get this done has not helped. Still getting my head round angularjs.

Comment: You might wanna give it a try: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: @ lealceldeiro thanks a bunch for your reply but ng-file-upload doesn't work  with ionic. I forgot to add that the angular js code is for an ionic project. Do u please have any idea on how i can achieve that with this code?